# How can I add custom js file and js file in magento 2 using requirejs

Tags: javascript, magento-2.1, requirejs

How can I add custom js file and compile using requirejs file in magento 2 ?

please give me details for this process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep your js file inside `app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Vendor_Modulename/web/js/custom.js`

You can add js using xml file with default.xml file,

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <head>
            <link src="Vendor_Modulename::js/custom.js"/>
        </head>
        <body>      
        </body>
    </page>
```

Run command to get js at compile time, `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

You can call js inside phtml file by calling,

```
<script>
  require(["jquery"],function($){ 
     // your js code
  })
</script>
```

Second way,

create requirejs-config.js file, inside **app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Vendor_Modulename/requirejs-config.js** file

add js file inside,  `app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Vendor_Modulename/web/js/customfile.js` file

```
 var config = {
        map: {
            '*': {
                customjs: 'Vendor_Modulename/js/customfile'
            }
        }
    };
```

call inside template file,,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery','customjs'],function($){

            $('selector').customjs({
            });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Just a note, it's advisable to use require.js (the second method here) instead of adding JS files via the XML. It's consistent with how Magento does it and it helps manage dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

requiredjs with file name (../view/frontend/requirejs-config.js)

```
var config = {
"map": {
    "*": {
        "<js_tag_name>": "<vendor>_<module_name>/js/<js_name>"
    }
}
```

};

Add your js to ../view/frontend/web/js/.js

```
define([
"jquery",], function($){
return function (config, element) {
    <your_js_code>
}});
```